# Re-view two maps from Old Cove

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

During the Old cove mission, you see two maps: one of the Mayan stones locations and one of some sort of Assassin camps.

Since the information from neither of these has transferred itself onto my main maps as far as I can tell, is there any way I can view these maps again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fiddling with the filters in the overall map.

If that doesn't work you'll have a bit more work but I did it this way:

While browsing the map you zoom in on locations (that you've uncovered) and all missions and collectibles will be displayed. Overall that's how I did it. I just decided on the Island and there I went sailing!

Hope I helped!

Comment: Yep, you're right - nothing on the overworld map but I zoomed in on enough towns and eventually found some templar hunts!

Comment: Hope I could help @Rawling